# React Native: Cannot vertically align an image to bottom of the screen

Tags: react-native

I am trying to align a large image to the bottom of the screen. It should be noted that width of the image is (much) larger than the width of the screen. My code is as follows:

**App.js**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
            source={LargeImage}
            style={styles.largeImage}
            resizeMode='contain'
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

**Styles.js**

```
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: '100%'
        height: '70%',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'cyan'
    },
    largeImage: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute'
        bottom: 0
    } 
});
```

The above code renders to this:
[image: mobile app screenshot]

where the red is the topmost container background, the light blue/cyan is the image container background, and the dark blue shape with the curved top is the large image. For some reason, the image is centered within the image container, despite the absolute positioning I've added in (removing this absolute positioning in the 'largeImage' block does not change the output at all).

How do I align this image so that it is flush against the bottom of the screen? I am running this on a physical Galaxy S9 Android device, running the latest version of react-native. Ideally I would like to accomplish this using absolute positioning.

Comment: as you set resizeMode='contain'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Solution was to calculate a scaled width and height based on the physical dimensions of the current screen. Style code below:

```
const imageAspectRatio = 1080 / 872;
const scaledWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const scaledHeight = scaledWidth / imageAspectRatio;

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: '100%'
        height: '70%',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'cyan'
    },
    largeImage: {
        width: scaledWidth,
        height: scaledHeight,
        position: 'absolute'
        bottom: 0
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Image Component` is actual vertically bottom, set backgroundColor and you'll see it

But as `resizeMode='contain'`,the actual image(not Image Component) will resize  to fit the Image ComponentI.
In this case, because of width is bigger height so the image will verticaly center inside Image Component

You need either set resizeMode='cover' or change abosolute property (top, bottom)

Answer (score 1):

You can use position **top**. I modified your `style code` and put in an example image.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
            source={{uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/27/19/47/turtle-863336__340.jpg"}}
            style={styles.largeImage}
            resizeMode='contain'
        />
    </View>
</View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        justifyContent:"flex-end"
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '70%',
        backgroundColor: 'cyan'

    },
    largeImage: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 100
    } 
});
```

To apply this equally to `all devices`, not to want it, you must adjust the `height` value of the `image`. The height of the `image` now is `100%`. But because your `image` `resizeMode` is '`contain`', you are trying to finish it in the center. If your `image resizeMode` was '`stretch`', you would have filled the screen. So you have to adjust the `height` and give the style `justifyContent` value.

the screen on which it is applied

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
            source={{uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/27/19/47/turtle-863336__340.jpg"}}
            style={styles.largeImage}
            resizeMode='contain'
        />
    </View>
</View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        justifyContent:"flex-end"
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '70%',
        backgroundColor: 'cyan',
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
    },
    largeImage: {
        width: '100%',
        height:"50%"
    } 
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this not work depending on the screen size? As it is, on my Galaxy S9 the picture is not quite flush with the bottom, there is a somewhat sizable gap.

Comment: In the case of a position, the position may be slightly different if the device is of different size because it refers to the absolute position.

Comment: @AdrianM  I have modified my answer to apply to all devices. Keep that in mind.

Comment: this still doesn't make the image flush with the bottom of the screen, which is the main thing I'm trying to do. I am trying to accomplish this with absolute positioning, but the reason that setting top: 100 doesn't work is because there is a variable distance to the bottom.

Comment: @AdrianM  https://snack.expo.io/SkznA1tQB  This is the link to execute my answer code. When you do this, the image is at the bottom.

Comment: @AdrianM I wrote an example of a code using 'top:100' as well as an example of image sizing and justifyContent for use on the entire device.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for images with size larger than the screen. I've posted my own solution that ended up working, using absolute positioning as well.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using absolute positioning, try using `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` in imageContainer.

For reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox